# Convert int 20171116101856 to yyyymmddhhmmss format to be used in datediff function

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

So I have this table that has date columns in int type.

```
last_run_date | last_run_time
   20171116   | 100234
```

Im trying to convert this two values into a datetime to be used in datediff statement.

this is my statement

```
SELECT 1
FROM V_Jobs_All_Servers vjas
WHERE JobName='DailyReports_xxxx' and Step_Name='xxxx'
and DATEDIFF(hour, Convert(varchar,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(cast(
Convert(varchar(100),vjas.last_run_date) +  Convert(varchar(100),vjas.last_run_time) as varchar)
,5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'),11,0,' '),14,0,':'),17,0,':')), Getdate()) <3
```

This works but only when the last_run_time value is in two digits hour format
101216, but whenever its one digit hour 91316 it fails with the following error,

```
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
```

I am on SQL Server 2005

Comment: I keep starting to construct an answer, and subsequently ask myself why on earth would someone architect a table like this.....

Comment: Well....that number is too large for an integer. What would you expect it to do? I am not a fan of storing dates and times as numbers like this. This is why we have the datetime datatype.

Comment: well this view pulls data from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps and this is a format that is being used in there.  nothing I can do about that.

Comment: There is a TON of inherent functionality builtin to the Date/DateTime/DateTimeOffset types. Trust the SQL server team. And why not transform in transit from `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`?

Comment: You can use `right(cast(1000000+last_run_time as varchar),6)` to get it to an even size regardless of value and then manipulate as you would.

Comment: Im sure there is a lot of them builtin but you didnt point to any.. so yeah thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting this value from `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`, there's a built-in function, `msdb.dbo.agent_datetime()`, to convert `last_run_date` and `last_run_time` to a datetime already:

```
select job_id,
    step_id,
    step_name,
    msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(nullif(last_run_date,0),nullif(last_run_time,0)) as last_run_datetime
from msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps
```

It is an undocumented function.  However, at least in my version of SQL Server (2012), that function has this definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION agent_datetime(@date int, @time int)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN
  (
    CONVERT(DATETIME,
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),@date / 10000) + N'-' + 
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),(@date % 10000)/100)  + N'-' +
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@date % 100) + N' ' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@time / 10000) + N':' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),(@time % 10000)/100) + N':' +        
          CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),@time % 100),
    120)
  )
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much I had no idea about this function and I'm surprised I didn't find it on google when I was searching for the ways to convert.

Comment: @MarkVoznyuk It is an undocumented function, but I've not had any trouble with it.

Comment: thanks for giving this information, caz ill be working with this date format a lot in the next few weeks and this will help me out tremendously

Answer (score 1):

You are massively over complicating this, just pad your time value with a leading `0` and convert from there:

```
declare @t table(last_run_date int, last_run_time int);
insert into @t values(20171116,90234),(20171116,100234);

select last_run_date
      ,last_run_time
      ,convert(datetime,cast(last_run_date as nvarchar(8))
                + ' '
                + stuff(stuff(right('0' + cast(last_run_time as nvarchar(6))
                                   ,6)
                             ,5,0,':')
                       ,3,0,':')
             ,112) as DateTimeData
from @t
```

Output:

```
+---------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| last_run_date | last_run_time |      DateTimeData       |
+---------------+---------------+-------------------------+
|      20171116 |        100234 | 2017-11-16 09:02:34.000 |
|      20171116 |        100234 | 2017-11-16 10:02:34.000 |
+---------------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: wow this worked, Thank you so much . Used that convert statement in my datediff function and it works, amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ugly way...

```
declare @table table (last_run_date int, last_run_time int)
insert into @table
values
(20171116,100234),
(20171116,91316)

select 
    cast(cast(cast(last_run_date as varchar) as datetime) + ' ' + stuff(stuff(last_run_time,len(last_run_time) - 1,0,':'),len(stuff(last_run_time,len(last_run_time) - 1,0,':')) - 4,0,':') as datetime)
from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (last_run_date int, last_run_time int)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES (20171116, 100234)

SELECT convert(datetime,CAST(last_run_date as varchar))
             + Convert(time, Dateadd(SECOND, Right(last_run_time,2)/1
                                           ,Dateadd(MINUTE, Right(last_run_time,4)/100
                                                          ,Dateadd(hour, Right(last_run_time,6)/10000
                                                                       ,'1900-01-01'
                                                                  )
                                                    )
                                     )
                      ) [DateConverted]
  FROM @temp
```

Produces Output:

```
DateConverted
2017-11-16 10:02:34.000
```

You can see how this works by doing each part individually.

```
SELECT Dateadd(hour, Right(last_run_time,6)/10000
                   ,'1900-01-01')
FROM @temp
```

Gives the hours position.

---

```
SELECT Dateadd(MINUTE, Right(last_run_time,4)/100
                     ,Dateadd(hour, Right(last_run_time,6)/10000
                     ,'1900-01-01'))
FROM @temp
```

Gives the hours plus minutes position.

---

Etc.

Comment: Could you explain why we adding '1900-01-01'

Comment: Just did it and it showed me 1900-01-01,  I never knew that, Thank you.

Comment: Might have overgeneralized there... it calculates hours position, minutes position, then seconds position.  Try to do each part of the algorithm individually and you will see.  I'll re-edit the problem for clarity.

Comment: I ran all of them separately and i see it now, really helpful information legit, thank you